# ROS package for detecting objects bounding box using kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, object-detection, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was looking for a package which works with ROS indigo and have the ability to detect objects position using Kinect and point cloud of the scene. I searched the ROS wiki but All the packages are either old or not working. If anyone worked with one of these packages and could make them work please help with finding a good package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207571/ros-package-for-detecting-objects-bounding-box-using-kinect/) by [D3GAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/22235/d3gan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-04-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PCL (pointclouds.org) with pcl_ros can do this. You can subscribe to the PointCloud2 messages from the kinect as pcl::PointCloud<> and pcl_ros will handle conversion for you. Then you can basically follow the tutorials on the PCL website.

---

Originally posted by [Joseph Duchesne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22955/joseph-duchesne/) with karma: 26 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karz](https://answers.ros.org/users/22805/karz/) on 2015-09-17**:
Do you have any idea how to make robot follow the bounding box? I have this problem [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/217603/how-to-get-coordinate-from-bounding-box/)